# How to find the lengths of the shortest paths in a directed graph in $O(m)$ steps?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Let $G = (V,A)$ be a directed graph for which it is true that if $(v_i , v_j) \in A$, it is implied that $i < j$.

Question: How does one construct an $\mathcal{O}(m)$ algorithm to find the lenghts of the shortest paths in $G$? (We use the notation $|V| = n$ and $|A| = m$).

This is a homework question. I think it's pretty though. I thought of modifying Dijkstra's or Bellman & Ford's algorithm to find an algorithm that answers this question. I couldn't do it though, because these algorithms have complexity $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ and $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ respectively. I don't know how to relate $m$ and $n$ in this general setting. I also tried first ordering the lenghts of the edges/arrows of the graph according to some algorithm first, but I couldn't apply that to the relevant question.

Comment: I am guessing it is an unweigthed directed graph. When you say lengths of the shortest paths, do you mean that given two nodes $v_i,v_j \in A$, you want to find the length of the shortest path between these two nodes in $G$ in $\mathcal{O}(m)$?

Comment: I think you can simply use [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain but BFS has complexity $\mathcal{O}(n+m)$, no?

Comment: You're right, but now that I think about it we have to be more specific. Do you want the lengths of all shortest paths for all pairs of vertices? In this case, you need $\mathcal O(n^2)$ steps anyway, because you have quadraticly many values to compute.

Comment: If I recall, Djikstra's algorithm is a single source algorithm. That is, it computes the shortest path between a given vertex and every other vertex and not the paths between every pair of vertices. Djikstra is $O(n^2)$ if you do not use a min-priority queue. If you do, it is $O(m lg(n))$